# How can I use the method in MapController? (flutter, osm plugin)

Tags: flutter

Hello I'm using flutter osm package.

https://pub.dev/documentation/flutter_osm_plugin/latest/osm_flutter/MapController-class.html
(this is package link)

I want to use clearAllRoad method in MapController
Could you show me an example, please?

```
class AirmetView extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  AirmetViewState createState() => AirmetViewState();
}

class AirmetViewState extends State<AirmetView> {
  MapController mapController = MapController(
      initMapWithUserPosition: false,
      initPosition: GeoPoint(latitude: 36.03428, longitude: 127.43402));

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return OSMFlutter(
      controller: mapController,
      trackMyPosition: false,
      initZoom: 6.5,
      stepZoom: 1.0,
      roadConfiguration: RoadConfiguration(
        startIcon: MarkerIcon(
          icon: Icon(
            Icons.person,
            size: 64,
            color: Colors.brown,
          ),
        ),
        roadColor: Colors.yellowAccent,
      ),
      markerOption: MarkerOption(
          defaultMarker: MarkerIcon(
        icon: Icon(
          Icons.person_pin_circle,
          color: Colors.blue,
          size: 56,
        ),
      )),
    );
  }
}
```